# Configuring logback in Tomcat app

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, classpath, logback

I have developed a JAR which I plan to use from a Tomcat app. The library depends on logback. During testing I've been using

```
-Dlogback.configurationFile=.\config\logback.xml
```

as a VM option to indicate the location of the configuration file.

How can I replicate the same thing in Tomcat? Note that logback can also find the configuration file on its own if its in the classpath. Is there a way to add the config file to the app's classpath in Tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

If you put it at the root of your Jar (src or src/main/resources), it will be available in Tomcat, too.

Comment: You're right. If I put it in src it does work, even on Tomcat. If I put it in src/main/resources it doesn't. However, what can I do to leave the config file out? For instance, if I want to modify the logger without rebuilding the JAR.